# Adding new from in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, game-engine

I am making a game in Visual Studio 2015 and for some odd reason I didn't think to make Form1 the title screen lol.  Did I miss my chance to add in screens (forms) before the actual game starts?  How do I add in Form2 and have the game start on form2 instead of form1?

I am using C# and Windows Forms Application.

Answer (score 1):

Open Program.cs in your project

Change: `Application.Run(new Form1());`

to: `Application.Run(new Form2());`

Answer (score 0):

You could add as much forms as you want to the project (In Solution Explorer right click on the project and select Add form). The form which is shown on start of the application is defined in the Main method in Program.cs.